How can I handle the delay caused by accessing the Room database?
I try to implement Room to read some items. I collect the items as state and assign an initial value:
val items by viewModel.items.collectAsState(
    initial = emptyList()
)

Scaffold(
    topBar = {/* ... */},
    content = {
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ){
                Text(
                    text = "No items"
                )
            }
        } else {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                items(
                    items = items
                ) { item ->
                    ItemCard(
                        item = item
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
)

The problem I'm facing is that even if I have items in the database, the "No items" is displayed for a few seconds until the items are loaded. How to display the correct content according to the list of items with no intermediate display?

Can you verify if you are getting some value in items? There might be problem in the database related code! Can you also post the database code?

@dev.tejasb Yes, I certainly get values inside the items object as long as I get the list populated with the correct items. The problem is that for a few seconds the list is empty and I get "No items" displayed.

Of course it going to happen because reading from db (Room) takes some time. If you don't want to show the message while the data is loading, use a flag to check if first read from db is done or not, if not, show loading UI, once first read is done, invert the flag, and your current logic will be followed next.

There is no way to avoid a waiting time while accessing the database. Your task as a developer is to clearly communicate to the user that there is some operation in progress, for example by displaying a CircularProgressIndicator.
A common pattern is to introduce a sealed class that represents three possible states:

Data is loading
Data is loaded
Data is not loaded because of an error

You can define a UiState class like this:
sealed class UiState {
    object Loading : UiState()
    // Please change type of data according to your needs
    data class Success(val data: List<String>) : UiState()
    data class Error(val message: String) : UiState()
}

Then, define a Flow in your ViewModel that exposes the UiState:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel(myRepository: MyRepository) {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Loading)
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState

    fun fetchData() {
        _uiState.value = UiState.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val foundItems = myRepository.loadItems()
                _uiState.value = UiState.Success(foundItems)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _uiState.value = UiState.Error("Error fetching data")
            }
        }
    }
}

Finally, update your Composable like this:
val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState(
    initial = UIState.Loading
)

Scaffold(
    topBar = {/* ... */},
    content = {
        when (uiState) {
            is UiState.Loading -> {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
            is UiState.Success -> {
                val items = uiState.data
                if (items.isEmpty()) {
                    //...
                } else {
                    LazyColumn(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    ) {
                        //...
                    }
                }
            }
            is UiState.Error -> {
                Text(text = state.message)
            }
        }
    }
)

Have a look at this blog post for more information.

Let me try your solution and get back to you. Thank you.

@AlwaysLearner Did this solution work for you?
